# How to get rid of a permanent old people smell?

Tags: smell

I'm living in a new place. On the second floor there is somebody who smells really bad, when I'm walking up the stairs its like a nursing home x 10 on that floor. I'm on the 4th and when I keep the windows open its fine but after having them closed for around a day or so, the smell creeps up here.

Keeping a window open every day isn't really practical since it goes down to -30C around here in the winter so what do you guys suggest to avoid the smell? I saw a commercial for an automatic air freshener for bathrooms in the tv once, are those any good?

Comment: There are a lot of different things one might describe as "old people smell" or "nursing home". Can you be more specific?  Moth balls? Old spice? Feces? Mildew?

Comment: Fre breeze spray or Oder be gone  depends on if it is tobacco or urin both have helped me.

Comment: @EdBeal Did you mean "Odor be gone", or "Older be gone"?

Comment: Yep Odor be gone , but Older would be funny . thanks tester

Comment: I'm an older person. I like the smell.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about tenant relations, not do-it-yourself home improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation calls for a conversation with your property manager. Airflow is probably the only solution, and it may be necessary to ask the downstairs resident to keep an exhaust fan on for a larger part of each day.

You might also investigate ionization filters, though they have their own issues. Ozone can be problematic for some.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely is that someone spilled something on that floor's floor & never cleaned it up or out. Complain to the Landlord & have them thoroughly clean all of the common areas.